# Contact us form in JSF

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am using JSF 2.2 and PrimeFaces 5.1 in my project. I create contact us page like this.

```
<h:form id="f">
    <p:messages id="messages" showDetail="true" autoUpdate="true" closable="true" />
    <p>From: <p:inputText  value="#{mail.from}"/></p>
    <p>Mail subject: <p:inputText value="#{mail.subject}"/></p>
    <p>Mail message: <p:inputTextarea value="#{mail.message}"/></p>

    <p><p:commandButton value="Submit"
                        actionListener="#{mail.sendMail()}" 
                        update="f:messages"/></p>
</h:form>
```

I want to that every user contact with admin through this page. When they filled up this form and submit then this message will send admin email. I tried several time with javaMail API but those way, I need to PasswordAuthentication. That is not possible because user not provide his/her email password in my contact us form. I am not interested use SMTP server. have any simple way to do this . I am tired with this. please help anyone ........ Thanks in advance

Comment: You may want to use a email sending service like sendgrid and then use their SMTP server in JavaMail.

Comment: Asking such questions on the subject JSF/PrimeFaces cannot lead you to the answer. Please ask it differently. This has whatsoever nothing to do with JSF/PrimeFaces. "*That is not possible because user not provide his/her email password in my contact us form. I am not interested use SMTP server.*" It is quite uncertain as to why you are not interested in using an SMTP server where users are not supposed to provide their own password for sending a mail.

Answer (score 0):

You should write java mailer using java mail api, and use some test smtp account, for example your google account and smtp credentials.

From from you should pass info with user mail and pass to java mail sender.

Please have a look at [mailer](http://www.mkyong.com/java/javamail-api-sending-email-via-gmail-smtp-example/)